# 5 блоков в ряд с плавающей шириной

Tags: css, вёрстка, html

У меня есть div с width:100% и высотой 200px

Как в него поставить 5 блоков div так, чтобы они занимали весь экран (растягивались, сужались)?
- я это решил width:20% каждому блоку, но из нюанса у меня все равно не получилось

Нюанс таков, мне надо, чтобы после первых четырех внутренних дивов был отступ справа пикселя на 3. Из-за этого у меня пятый блок съезжает.

Скрин чего нужно: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q48kC.jpg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например `flex`:

```css
.col {
  background: #36a9e0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 20%;
}

.col+.col {
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Либо можно учесть размер ширины блоков с учетом отступа:

```css
.col {
  background: #36a9e0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 19.8%;
  float: left;
}

.col+.col {
  margin-left: .25%;
}

.row {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Во втором варианте при развороте на весь экран блоки занимают не всю ширину.

Comment: спасибо, не подумал, что можно 0.....% использовать, так сделал:   width: 19.9%;
margin-right: 0.125%;  у блоков и у последнего убрал margin-right

Answer (score 4):

Можно при помощи вычисляемой ширины и селектора `+`.

```css
article {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  width: calc((100% - 4*3px) / 5);
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  float: left;
}

div + div {
  margin-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</article>
```

Или при помощи флексбокса и вычисляемой ширины:

```css
article {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div {
  width: calc((100% - 4*3px) / 5);
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</article>
```

Comment: спасибо, не знал, что есть calc(), но привычнее было заюзать проценты

Comment: @GenRiH может быть и привычнее, но на некоторых разрешениях у вас съедет блок или будет дыра.

Comment: @Crantisz собственно, так уже и происходит из-за особенностей округления дробных пикселей.

Answer (score 4):

Вариант с `display: table;`

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.blocks{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border-spacing: 3px 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.blocks > div{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: royalblue;
}
.blocks > div:nth-of-type(even){
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Похоже на цвета Болоньи :)